# How do I delete the Administrator account?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts

I would like to delete the built-in "Administrator" account on non-domain-joined Windows 2008 Server (R2).

The user registry (ntuser.dat) for the Administrator account has become corrupted. I have other users in the Administrators group so I don't need the Administrator account.

Is this even possible? The OS says "Cannot perform this operation on built-in accounts." I thought though I saw reference to deleting the account in other places as a security measure. As far as I know you can only disable it.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware, you can't delete the account, but you can rename it. If you're having problems with the ntuser.dat file for that account on a particular server or workstation then simply delete the user profile for that user on the affected server or workstation.

Comment: Agreed. Just to re-iterate: log on as another member of the Administrators group and delete the affected profile.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can delete them, heres a [TechNET](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/fb8101c4-8486-4d33-b15d-04ebccde0fea) forum thread talking about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't delete it, you should be able to fix it - log in as another administrator account and then Delete the Administrator Profile.  When the Administrator user logs in again next time, it should recreate the profile from the Default Profile.