# Admin account - Cannot Remote Desktop In

Tags: windows-server-2008

We recently had the server hacked and it appears we cannnot login, via RDC (remote desktop connection) anymore. I can create and delete any other profile on the server but not this one.

I've renamed it and changed the password. The hack has disabled Malware so how can I reset the Administrator setting? I've looked at [How do I delete the Administrator account?](https://serverfault.com/questions/290328/how-do-i-delete-the-administrator-account) which suggests not to/you cannot delete the original login.

I will, as an aside, be setting up a new server and have checked the actual code via anti-virus and malware and believe we've removed the malware, however I'm nervous not being able to login with the Admin.

Comment: `We recently had the server hacked ` - Wipe it and start from scratch. `I will, as an aside, be setting up a new server and have checked the actual code via anti-virus and malware and believe we've removed the malware, however I'm nervous not being able to login with the Admin.` - Wipe it and start from scratch.

Comment: I thought that might be the only answer  to be honest. Working on that today.